# Navigating between data in DataGrid WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have checkboxes that represent the modules in my program that a user can access.

You can see from the DataGrid that the modules in the fourth column are created from "DataContext.ModuleCollection", where as the rows for the DataGrid are created from UserCollection. I would like the User_ID to be the content for each checkbox. This will be set in the checkbox style which I have attempted at the bottom without much success.

My issue is, the checkbox is at Module level (in the data) and I need to figure a way to get back to the User level to get the User_ID.

User_ID is part of the row's dataset, e.g. a User record.

How do I get User_ID in the below style is the question?

[image]

Below is my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Job_Title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ModuleCollection}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" CanVerticallyScroll="False" CanHorizontallyScroll="False"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemRotatedText}" Text="{Binding ModuleName}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ModuleCollection}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" CanVerticallyScroll="False" CanHorizontallyScroll="False"></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckbox}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Below is my check style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemCheckbox" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=User_ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: *I would like the User_ID to be the content for each checkbox.* You want the same `User_ID` value from each row to appear in *all* five `Checkbox`es on that row?

Comment: Yes it may seem odd, but I just want to figure out how to get a reference it. I will eventually be sending this to a converter at the same level as the checkbox.

Comment: This is the fourth time I have re-worded this question, so I would really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I know... it *has* been hard to understand... answering now. Give me 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `Binding Path` won't work because you're trying to access the `User_ID` property *from the `DataGridRow`*, which of course, doesn't have one... you *should* have an error in your Output Window in Visual Studio... pay close attention to these errors, as they'll help you fix your problems.

So what `Binding Path` *can* you use? Well, you're right as far as the fact that we have to use a `RelativeSource Binding`... try this instead:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemCheckbox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.User_ID, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
</Style>
```

What we're *attempting* to do here is to data bind to the `User_ID` value that should be found in the object set as the `DataContext` of the `DataGridRow`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ahhh yeah, what I was thinking wouldn't work anyway as I was trying to bind to the whole collection and you need to bind to the current item. You're only getting these horrible problems though because of the way that you've organised (or disorganised) your data model. Those `CheckBox`es should be data bound from one or more properties that are *actually* in your `User class` and not in this separate collection. I'd fix your model now before you get worse problems.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

You now want to know how to bind to the whole data object rather than a property from that object. For future reference, please see the [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information. However, you just need to think about this... if `DataContext.User_ID` gets you the `User_ID` property value of a `User` object, what do *you* think would return the whole `User` object? That's right... just remove the property:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemCheckbox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I kind of see where your going however it came back with the following in the Output window: System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'User_ID' property not found on 'object' ''Module' (HashCode=62906887)'. BindingExpression:Path=User_ID; DataItem='Module' (HashCode=62906887); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in UserManagement.dll

Comment: I get what you mean, create a collection of modules for each user? Still there must be a way if not for this exact example to reach the User_ID from the checkbox. Nevermind just found it, swapped out the x:Type DataGrid for DataGridRow and it has done it. Thanks for your patience and I will put your advice on the data model into action next

Comment: one more related question. If I wanted to bind from the same position, to the User object, instead of one of its properties how would you do this?